# option tags created from Zend_Form_Element_Select wrong

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, forms, zend-form

I'm using the Zend_Form_Element_Select to create my select list, but when I view the source, the options tags look like this:

```
<select name="things" id="things">
    <option value="thing1" label="Thing 1">Thing 1</option>
    <option value="thing2" label="Thing 2">Thing 2</option>
    <option value="thing3" label="Thing 3">Thing 3</option>
</select>
```

the label attribute doesn't need to be in there. It has no use being in there. The value should match what's in label. Here's the code I used:

```
$things = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('things');
$things->setLabel('Things:');
$things->setRequired(TRUE);
$things->addMultiOptions(array(
    'thing1'=>'Thing 1',
    'thing2'=>'Thing 2',
    'thing3'=>'Thing 3'
));
$this->addElement($things);
```

Am I going about this all wrong or is this just the way Zend works and I just have to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array you pass in takes the form value=>label, so you would want to do

```
$things->addMultiOptions(array(
  'Thing 1'=>'Thing 1',
  'Thing 2'=>'Thing 2',
  'Thing 3'=>'Thing 3'
));
```

Comment: But that sets the label to "Thing 1" etc, but the value is set to the placement in the array "0", etc.

Comment: apologies, after checking the docs the shorthand option is a non-option. So you must use the syntax from the first example.

Comment: Sadly, I think this was a case of me over-thinking the solution. The label tag is just extra in the option tag. Serves no real purpose except in IE7+. Thanks for your help, Joe and Marcin (below).

Answer (score 0):

Attribute `label` "specifies a shorter label for an option" and it is a valid attribute of an `option` tag. So because all your options are different, the labels will also be different.

Comment: It is also an attribute that's only supported in IE7+. http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_option_label.asp

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you remove first?

```
->removeDecorator('Label')
                                    ->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');
```